# Result of each repeat of the loop to different file WIN BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to resolve simple problem - Saving to different file when loop repeats. I know im getting results because when I am doing >>file.txt 
i am getting all restults into one file. It would be GREAT to save results to different files each time(and name this file by text from variable. but there is something wrong. It saves the results of last loop iteration.

```
    @echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set vidx=0
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in (list2.csv) do (
        SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
        set var!vidx!=%%A
        rxrepl -f temp.txt -s "xNAMEx" -r "%%A">file___%var!vidx!%.txt
    )
```

Comment: Is delayed expansion enabled?

Comment: To enable it just place `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at beggining of the file

Comment: still doesnt work:(, I uploaded new code

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this
`file___%var!vidx!%.txt` by this `file___!var!!vidx!!!.txt`

Comment: cool, thx it almost works- it makes files- thanks! but file looks like file___1 ,file___2  - like variables stored in vidx. but it should look like file___Name1 file___Name2 (names should be taken from %%A, stored in var1, var2, var3 etc..

Comment: I made variable set name=%%A and repaced yours !var!!vidx!!!.txt with !name! :) thanks a lot! have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any variables to get the result you are looking for. Also, the `*` is usesless in `"tokens=1*"` if you never reference variable `%%B`. And `"tokens=1"` is the default. So all you need is:

```
for /F "delims=;" %%A in (list2.csv) do rxrepl -f temp.txt -s "xNAMEx" -r "%%A">"file___%%A.txt"
```

If you really want to build an "array" of var.N values, you can use FINDSTR to prefix each line with an incrementing number (line number).

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:;" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" list2.csv') do (
  set "var.%%A=%%B"
  set "var.cnt=%%A"
  rxrepl -f temp.txt -s "xNAMEx" -r "%%B">"file___%%B.txt"
)

:: Display the "array" values
for /l %%N in (1 1 %var.cnt%) do echo var.%%N=!var.%%N!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use just `...>"file___%%~A.txt"` instead of erroneous `>file___%var!vidx!%.txt`

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in (list2.csv) do (
    SET /A "vidx+=1"
    set "var!vidx!=%%~A"
    echo loopvar %%%% A=%%~A "file___%%~A.txt"
    rem next line shows how to treat array-like names 
    call set "filenamepart=%%var!vidx!%%" 
    echo filenamepart=!filenamepart! "file___!filenamepart!.txt"
    rem rxrepl -f temp.txt -s "xNAMEx" -r "%%A">"file___%%~A.txt"
)
```